# Why is 'this' undefined

Tags: javascript, object, methods, undefined, this

```
var person = {
  name: "John",
  message: function () {    
    console.log("Hello, " + this.name)
  }
}

var messageFunc = person.message
messageFunc();
```

why am i getting "Hello, undefined" when the method here is declared to a variable? why cant it read this?

Comment: Because your person is not a class

Comment: In JS, `this` in a method refers to the object called the method, not the object originally defined the method. You've to bind the context: `var messageFunc = person.message.bind(person);`.

Comment: `this` in the context is pointing to global and it can find any variable with name so its undefined